# Rooting a Samsung Galaxy S1

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s

Once my HTC EVO 4G LTE was stolen, I had to switch back to my old Samsung Galaxy S. The phone still works fairly well for a fossil, but it's full of unremovable bloatware and Sprint crapplications. I want to root the phone for the simple purpose of removing Asphalt5, NASCARZone, and the like. Unfortunately, I've never even tried to root a phone before, and the device is pretty old, so I wasn't able to find a root program for it. Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a good guide on Phandroid](http://androidforums.com/galaxy-s-all-things-root/163892-samsung-galaxy-s-root-guide-updated-19-18-pm-est-apr-08-2011-major-cleanup.html)

Simply put:

If on firmware version 2.1; Download a file, place it in the root folder, flash via recovery.

If on firmware version 2.2; Download 4Root.

If on firmware version 2.3; Download super one click.

If there is anything you don't understand comment on this and I'll edit my answer.

[SuperOneClick on Cnet.com](http://download.cnet.com/SuperOneClick/3000-2094_4-75447027.html) as the link is broken for some.

[The XDA page I get for SuperOneClick](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682) from Phandroid.

Comment: I found 2 different specs listing version 2.x. Firmware is 2.3.6. Kernel is 2.6.35.7. Since you only listed through 2.3, I would figure it was the firmware version that matters. The Phandroid link seems to support that, but I want to be sure before I  accidentally brick this phone.

Comment: Also, the download for SuperOneClick seems to be broken. It says that the link is blocked for copyright reasons.

Comment: Yes it is the firmware. I will update the answer with a link to SuperOneClick download from Cnet.